# Error when storing and calling values from a dynamic array: program output not as expected

Tags: c, arrays, combinations

I have written a program that calculates the numbers 1-8 in binary (each as four bits), stores them in an array and then prints the resulting string. The output should be: 0000,0001,0010,0011,0100…etc. However my program is printing: 0000,0001,0000,0001 and I can't seem to find the problem so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
      int no,i=0,j,val,small[3],l;
      int *d;
      d = malloc(sizeof(int)*500);
      l=0;
      if (d != NULL) {
      printf("1\n");
      } else {
      printf("0\n");
      }

      for(j=0;j<4;j++) //sets initial 0000 combination
      {
        d[j]=0;
      }

      for(no=1;no<8;no++)  //loop for numbers 1-8
      {
        val=no;
        while(val>0)         //decimal to binary conversion
        {

           small[i]=val%2;
           i++;
           val=val/2;
           l++;
        }
        i=0;
          printf("%d\n",l);
        if(l<4)                     //creating 4 bit binary number
        {
            if(l=1)
            {
                small[3]=small[0];
            }
            else
            {
                for(j=(l-1);j>=0;j--)
                {
                    small[(j+(4-l))]=small[j];
                }
            }
            for(j=0;j<(4-l);j++)
            {
                small[j]=0;
            }
        }
        l=0;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)            //storing binary number in dynamic array
        {
            d[(4*no)+j]=small[j];
            small[j]=0;
        }
      }

      for(j=0;j<(4*(no-1))+4;j++) //printing array
      {
            printf("%d",d[j]);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if (l = 1)
```

should be:

```
if (l == 1)
```

You should be leery, extremely leery, of code like:

```
int i = 0;
…

for (no = 1; no < 8; no++) // loop for numbers 1-8
{
    val = no;
    while (val > 0)         // decimal to binary conversion
    {
        small[i] = val % 2;
        i++;
        val = val / 2;
        l++;
    }
    i = 0;
```

The assignment `i = 0;` sets up the next iteration of the the `for (no = 1; …)` loop correctly, but it is 'action at a distance' compared with:

```
for (no = 1; no < 8; no++) // loop for numbers 1-8
{
    int i = 0;
    int val = no;
    for (int val = no; val > 0; val /= 2)
    {
        small[i++] = val % 2;
        l++;
    }
```

The variable `l` is also puzzling; in the first iteration, it is in sync with `i`, but it is used after the loop shown, unlike `i`.

The loop:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        d[(4 * no) + j] = small[j];
        small[j] = 0;
    }
```

reads and writes outside the bounds of the array `small` which has only 3 elements.  The simple fix for that is to change the size of `small` to 4.

The printing code doesn't separate the 4-digit numbers from each other.
There are various ways to fix that, but this one works:

```
for (j = 0; j < (4 * (no - 1)) + 4; j++) // printing array
{
    printf("%d", d[j]);
    if (j % 4 == 3)
        putchar('\n');
}
```

There's really no need to use `malloc()` to allocate the array `d`; it only needs to be 32, but `int d[500];` would work too.  There's then no need for the code that prints 0 or 1 depending on whether the allocation worked or not.  And there's no need to ensure that we don't use the (non-)allocated space if the allocation fails.  We can observe that neither `<string.h>` nor `<math.h>` were used, and now `<stdlib.h>` is unnecessary too.

#### Initial cleanup

This leads to the initial partially cleaned up code (where the 'action at a distance' problems are not fixed):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int no, i = 0, j, val, small[4], l;
    int d[32];
    l = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) // sets initial 0000 combination
    {
        d[j] = 0;
    }

    for (no = 1; no < 8; no++) // loop for numbers 1-8
    {
        val = no;
        while (val > 0)         // decimal to binary conversion
        {
            small[i] = val % 2;
            i++;
            val = val / 2;
            l++;
        }
        i = 0;
        printf("%d\n", l);
        if (l < 4)                     // creating 4 bit binary number
        {
            if (l == 1)
            {
                small[3] = small[0];
            }
            else
            {
                for (j = (l - 1); j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    small[(j + (4 - l))] = small[j];
                }
            }
            for (j = 0; j < (4 - l); j++)
            {
                small[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        l = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)            // storing binary number in dynamic array
        {
            d[(4 * no) + j] = small[j];
            small[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < (4 * (no - 1)) + 4; j++) // printing array
    {
        printf("%d", d[j]);
        if (j % 4 == 3)
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
0000
0001
0001
0011
0001
0101
0011
0111
```

#### Continuing the process

Let's deal with some of the 'action at a distance' issues.  I'm assuming you have C99, so the `for` loops can declare the variables in the loop control unless the value is needed after the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int small[4];
    int d[32];

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        d[j] = 0;

    for (int no = 1; no < 8; no++)
    {
        int l = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int val = no;
        while (val > 0)
        {
            small[i] = val % 2;
            i++;
            val = val / 2;
            l++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", l);
        if (l < 4)
        {
            if (l == 1)
                small[3] = small[0];
            else
            {
                for (int j = (l - 1); j >= 0; j--)
                    small[(j + (4 - l))] = small[j];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < (4 - l); j++)
                small[j] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            d[(4 * no) + j] = small[j];
            small[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4 * 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", d[j]);
        if (j % 4 == 3)
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
0000
0001
0001
0011
0001
0101
0011
0111
```

The same erroneous output.  The cleanup has done no damage, even if it is not yet clear that it's done any good.

#### Revamping the processing into `small`

The loop populating the `small` array puts the digits into `small` in the reverse of the order that they need to go into `d`.  It also doesn't always set each of the 4 digits in `small`.  It would be better to simply set all 4 digits each time.  We then need to copy the 4 digits from `small` into `d` in reverse order.  This removes a lot of code; it also starts to produce the correct answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int small[4];
    int d[32];

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        d[j] = 0;

    for (int no = 1; no < 8; no++)
    {
        int val = no;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            small[i] = val % 2;
            val = val / 2;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            d[(4 * no) + j] = small[3 - j];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4 * 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", d[j]);
        if (j % 4 == 3)
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
```

#### Final code tightening

In fact, we don't need the `small` array; we could simply put the digits into `d` directly.  There's also no need to treat 0 specially:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d[32];

    for (int no = 0; no < 8; no++)
    {
        int val = no;
        for (int i = 4; i > 0; --i)
        {
            d[4 * no + i - 1] = val % 2;
            val /= 2;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4 * 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", d[j]);
        if (j % 4 == 3)
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
```

It is still a slightly unusual way of processing the data, but given that the output should have the binary digits represented in `d` in the order required, it is semi-reasonable (assuming that a calculation is necessary, rather than simply writing out an initializer for the array).

Comment: regarding the last example, line: 'val /= 2;' the invokes an integer divide.  which will fail when val = 1 or val = 0;  suggest: 'val >>= 1;' which will always work, invokes a simple code sequence that has no call to the integer divide function, so will be much faster

Comment: regarding the last example, line: 'd[4 * no + i - 1] = val % 2;' invokes a module function.  which will work, but is not necessary.  suggest a simple: 'd[4 * no + i - 1] = val&0x01;' and if the above 'for' loop ran from 3 to >=0 then the '-1' can be removed from the equation.

Comment: regarding the last example: line: 'for (int j = 0; j < 4 * 8; j++)' 1) may have the constant multiplication optimized out by the compiler, but would be better to keep it simple with: 'for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)'  suggest certain 'magic numbers' like '32' be generated via #define's rather than splattered all over the code

Comment: finally, there is no reason to generate/keep the generated 0/1 values in an array.  just print them as they are generated.  Note: this would require generating the 0/1 values in the correct order.  Or using the current generation process, the d[4]' would be plenty and outputing the numbers as soon as 4 are generated.  then reusing the D[] array which would remove the '*4' entries from the calculated offsets into D[]

Comment: @user3629249: since when does `val /= 2;` fail when `val` is 1 or 0?  The answer is 0 in both cases, but that's fine and expected and desired.  Yes, you can use `val >>= 1;` to divide positive numbers by 2.  You'll probably find the compiler does that for you; it is unnecessary micro-optimization.  Yes, there are also ways of getting the last bit other than `val % 2`; again, the compiler might do it for you and it is micro-optimization.  Yes; you can write the loops differently.

Comment: @user3629249: you don't know, and I don't know, what the larger context from which this code was extracted.  The question clearly wanted the data in the array; the answer preserves the data in the array (but makes sure the correct data is in the array).  Of course if you rewrite the rules of engagement, you can produce a different program.

Comment: 1/2 in integer division is always 0,  0/2 in integer division is always 0.  Only when the value is 2/2 (or greater) does it give an valid value other than 0 and even then, 3 (and other odd numbers 5,7) /2 will round down.

Comment: Given that the numbers are 0...7, they are always positive.

Comment: And I also teach my grandmother how to suck eggs.  I'm not sure what you're getting at.  I know that; I'm relying on that; I expect, desire, want that behaviour.  If something else happened, the code wouldn't work correctly.  I don't see what point you are making with this questioning of the result of integer division.  Look, if you want to create an alternative answer, be my guest.  Leave my answer alone — I will look askance at edits to it.  Create your own answer that does things the way you think it should be done.  Then, please, delete these comments.